# Timeout waiting for server response exception while inserting data into cassandra database using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, exception, cassandra, timeout

Getting below exception while inserting data using rest api's.

```
Exception At: com.yagnaiq.repository.impl.ProductRepositoryImpl
org.springframework.cassandra.support.exception.CassandraUncategorizedException: [/172.31.19.55:9042] Timed out waiting for server response; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [/172.31.19.55:9042] Timed out waiting for server response
    at org.springframework.cassandra.support.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:129)
```

I have done the below configuration for cassandra database

```
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 200000
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 50000
```

Data to insert is around 30000 records.

All my servers are hosted on AWS including cassandra and tomcat for rest.

Also getting exception in datastax while executing the query. Attached the screenshot for the same.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR1Lo.png)

Comment: Without any code we cannot help you. Also make sure you format them as well. Edit your post please. Concerning the timeout, I think it's due to amazon ec2 security group. You need to allow connection from outside.

Comment: All servers are on aws. Connection is allowed . Data is getting inserted for some tables but for some tables its not getting inserted and tables in which it is not getting inserted is not consistent.

Comment: Ok Please edit your post by adding some source codes as well as your configuration files and your cassandra schema.